# java.lang.StackOverflowError when running cucumber java from Katalon Studio

Tags: java, docker, jenkins-pipeline, cucumber, katalon-studio

when ever we run:

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords as CucumberKW

CucumberKW.runFeatureFileWithTags(featureFileFolder, (([finalTag]) as String[]))
```

we are using cucumber jar wrapped inside katalon Studio testing framework.

running from jenkins as part of docker image, sometimes it's causing

```
Keyword runFeatureFileWithTags was failed (Root cause: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterator$FileIterator.next(FileResourceIterator.java:73)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.FlatteningIterator.moveToNext(FlatteningIterator.java:29)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.FlatteningIterator.moveToNext(FlatteningIterator.java:27)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.FlatteningIterator.moveToNext(FlatteningIterator.java:27)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.FlatteningIterator.moveToNext(FlatteningIterator.java:27)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.FlatteningIterator.moveToNext(FlatteningIterator.java:27)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.FlatteningIterator.moveToNext(FlatteningIterator.java:32)
```

and the tests are not being executed because of this.
Not sure what is the root cause for this. Any insight or help is much appreciated

Comment: I don't think `CucumberKW` is part of Cucumber.

Comment: What are you using to run Cucumber and which version?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated. we are using Cucumber wrapped inside Katalon (we use it to run our automated tests.) @M.P.Korstanje

Comment: Don't know that one. But it is using an old version of Cucumber. You may have a loop in your files system due to a symlink.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @M.P.Korstanje, I am not sure what is symlink but how can I find if I have a loop in my files system ?